# automatic comment help

Tags: feature-request, comment

I was reading [a question on aviation.stackexchange](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/5139/is-it-legal-to-fly-a-quadrocopter-drone-into-an-airport-what-will-happen) that had a number of comments.  When I clicked on add/show comments to read the rest a small help window came up on the miniformatting in the comment field.  Most were things I know, but there was a Learn More button that took me to a longer page that could be very helpful.  This should be added to math (and the other sites on the network).  Does the linebreak option there work here?  It has been requested.

Comment: Possibly the "help" button that you can see below the "Add Comment" button?

Comment: @AsafKaragila:  Yes, that works fine.  On aviation you get the help automatically when you open the comment window.

Comment: Have you tried other sites (in particular beta stage sites)?

Comment: In the [Learn More](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) page, it mentions the linebreak option.  
However, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @AsafKaragila:  Physics and Puzzling (beta) work just like math.  You have to click on help.

Comment: @robjohn:  I saw that.  That was one of the things that prompted me to post this, as I have been frustrated by not having linebreaks in comments and saw some meta thread on it some time ago.

Comment: @RossMillikan: There
are$\tag*{}$ ways to achieve linebreaks.

Comment: @robjohn:Clever!$\tag*{}$ $\qquad\qquad$I like that.

Answer (score 4):

The comment help is shown automatically to users [under 100 reputation points](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172746/can-we-auto-show-commenting-help-for-new-users?lq=1#comment512924_172749). This is SE network-wide. You saw it on Aviation because of that one downvote that dropped your reputation below the threshold.

Newlines in comments have been requested many times and [declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197/259867) as many times.

Comment: So Ross would only have to lose 128,818 points for this on MSE? I suppose we're going to have a big bounty party.